# How to set image inside table cell in mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

Im using mPDF for reporting. I want to display image in the cell of a table. The images are as binary data. 
 The code that I have tried is

```
while($rows=$clist->fetchRow()) 
{
    $html='<tr style="border: 0.1pt solid #cccccc;">
        <td> '.$rows['name'].'</td>
        <td> '.$rows['address_1'].', '.$rows['address_2'].'</td>';
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        if($studphoto!='')
        {
            $mpdf->Image($studphoto,500,$p,11,13);
        }
        $html='</tr>';

}
```

here I want `$mpdf->Image($studphoto,500,$p,11,13);` this image come in a table cell. I have tried using `'<img src="'.$studphoto.'">'` but this code is not working for some images. thats why Im using `$mpdf->Image($studphoto,500,$p,11,13);` Please somebody help me to solve this...

Comment: Have you tried by echoing `$mpdf->Image($studphoto,500,$p,11,13);`?and this is not working for some images...means?

Comment: And `$studphoto` is binary format..??

Comment: echoing not works... yes '$studphoto' is binary data

Comment: `binary data` means..?as you said in last question it is with `base64`?

Comment: @Gautam3164 yes the same data since that images are not displaying, I have used Image() function but here the problem is i want this output in table td